# How to implement a generic mongoose dao in typescript

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I'am pretty new to Typescript and having a hard time figuring out whats wrong with the following generic dao class:

```js
import { Document, Model, Types } from 'mongoose';

interface Entity<T = Types.ObjectId> { _id: T }

export abstract class AbstractDao<T extends Entity, D extends Document<T['_id']> & T> {
  protected model: Model<D>;

  async findById(id: T['_id']): Promise<T> {
    return this.model.findOne({ _id: id }).lean();
  }

  async update(id: T['_id'], update: Partial<Omit<T, '_id'>>): Promise<any> {
    return this.model.updateOne({ _id: id }, { $set: update }).exec();
  }
}
```

Typescript is complaining about both **filter queries** `{_id: id }`:

```
TS2345: Argument of type '{ _id: T["_id"]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FilterQuery<D>'.
  Type '{ _id: T["_id"]; }' is not assignable to type '{ [P in keyof D]?: Condition<D[P]>; }'.
```

and the **update query** `{ $set: update }`:

```
TS2345: Argument of type '{ $set: Partial<Omit<T, "_id">>; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UpdateWithAggregationPipeline | UpdateQuery<D>'.
  Types of property '$set' are incompatible.
    Type 'Partial<Omit<T, "_id">>' is not assignable to type 'AnyKeys<_UpdateQueryDef<D>> & AnyObject'.
      Type 'Partial<Omit<T, "_id">>' is not assignable to type 'AnyKeys<_UpdateQueryDef<D>>'.
        Type 'keyof D' is not assignable to type 'Exclude<keyof T, "_id">'.
          Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'Exclude<keyof T, "_id">'.
            Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Exclude<keyof T, "_id">'.
```

The error is somehow related to the generic model definition. when replacing the document type as follows the errors are gone:

```
class Content {_id: Types.ObjectId}

export type ContentDocument = Content & mongoose.Document;

export abstract class AbstractDao<T extends Entity, D extends Document<T['_id']> & T> {
  protected model: Model<ContentDocument>;

  async findById(id: T['_id']): Promise<T> {
    return this.model.findOne({_id: id }).lean();
  }

//...
}
```

I'am using `"mongoose": "^6.0.13"`, `"typescript": "^4.5.2"`. I know I could just cast to `<any>` but I'd prefer to have a clean typesystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using an actual class as generic model as follows:

```js
export class BaseDBObject<T = Types.ObjectId> {
  @Exclude()
  public _id: T;

  @Expose()
  public id: string;

  @Expose()
  public __v: number;
}
```

```js
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { BaseDBObject } from './basedbobject';

export abstract class AbstractDao<T extends BaseDBObject> {
  protected model: Model<BaseDBObject>;

  async findById(id: T['_id']): Promise<any> {
    return this.model.findOne({_id: id}).lean();
  }

  async update(id: T['_id'], update: Partial<Omit<T, '_id'>>): Promise<any> {
    return this.model.updateOne({_id: id}, { $set: update }).exec();
  }
}
```

Still not sure why it did not work in the first place, but now I don't have to define the document anymore, which is nice...